# How do RUN docker in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, macos, kind

```
FROM kindest/node:v1.25.3

RUN docker pull some-image:latest
```

If I call `docker build` on my MacOS machine, I get

```
failed to dial "/run/containerd/containerd.sock": context deadline exceeded: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout"
```

**Background:** I am playing around with `kind`. If I start my kind cluster it needs to load a lot of images. I would like to shorten that by using a custom node image, which already has all docker images pre-loaded.

I also tried

```
FROM kindest/node:v1.25.3

COPY 4188262a351f156e8027ff81693d771c35b34b668cbd61e59c4a4490dd5c08f3.tar /4188262a351f156e8027ff81693d771c35b34b668cbd61e59c4a4490dd5c08f3.tar
RUN tar -xvf /4188262a351f156e8027ff81693d771c35b34b668cbd61e59c4a4490dd5c08f3.tar -C /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/blobs/sha256
RUN rm /4188262a351f156e8027ff81693d771c35b34b668cbd61e59c4a4490dd5c08f3.tar
```

but this does not seem to load the image properly

Comment: You won't have a Docker daemon running in the container that builds Dockerfiles...

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: You don't and you shouldn't. Something you can do is `docker pull` and `docker save` the images to tarballs on the host, and if `kind` supports some sort of node init script, `docker load` them in that script. (Of course assuming the node uses Docker at all...)

Answer (score 2):

You usually can't `RUN docker` at all.  One of the big reasons, as noted in a comment, is that whatever the main container process normally is isn't running in the Dockerfile; there isn't a Docker daemon you can talk to.

However, the [kind Node image documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/design/node-image/) notes

> `/kind/images/` contains various `*.tar` files which are [Docker image archives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), these images will be loaded by the cluster tooling prior to running kubeadm

So if you can pick out the Docker images you're going to use

```bash
sed -ne 's/^ *image: *//p' *-deployment.yaml
```

then you can individually save each of those images

```bash
for image in ...; do
  docker pull "$image"
  docker save -o "$image.tar" "$image"
done
```

and then include those in your custom node image

```bash
FROM kindest/node:v1.25.3
COPY *.tar /kind/images/
```

Often for this kind of setup, there's a pattern of putting the content needed for the initialization somewhere a first-time startup script can find it.  This is similar to database images, for example: you don't directly run SQL commands in a Dockerfile but instead put an initialization script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.  This is a similar pattern where you can't pull the images in the Dockerfile but you can at least put the content in the image, and they won't need to be (re-)fetched over the network.

(Even if you're just saving an image to a file, you can't do this via `docker` commands in a Dockerfile.  I believe there are other commands that can do this that don't require connecting to a Docker daemon, but I can't recommend any of those in particular.)

Comment: `COPY *.tar /kind/images/` is this the correct path? Do I just need to copy tars into `/kind/mages`?

Comment: That's what the kind documentation implies; I haven't tried this myself.  (When I do use kind or minikube I'm usually content to let Kubernetes pull images on its own.)

Comment: Tried it. Kind still needs to load the images. I assume that `crictl` is not aware of those images being there.

Comment: I also tried directly copying them to `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/blobs/`, which failed as well. This is why I assumed that I need to use `crictl` to load the images